# Run build job inside container with Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

everybody.
I'm trying running a step "build job" inside a container, but doesn't work.
The container is create, but the job that i call run outside of container.

The groovy code:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label "master"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            agent {
                docker { image 'node:16.13.1-alpine' }
            }
            steps {
                build job: 'builds/jobTest'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If i just run a command inside the step (example below), that command works inside the container.
But if a call the other job, nothing works inside the container.
Example when command works inside the container:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label "master"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            agent {
                docker { image 'node:16.13.1-alpine' }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work like that. `build()` directive will just schedule the Job and since `builds/jobTest` has it's own Pipeline definition it will run with the Agents you have specified in the `jobTest` Pipeline definition.